# Is there a way to make many AD Users change their password at next logon? Rather than setting this for each user one at a time?

Tags: active-directory, password

I want practically all of my AD users in my organization to change their password the next time they log in. I have roughly 160 users. I would also like to not include a few select members. Is there a quick way to do this rather than going through AD and checking the box for each user one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all the users you want to change password. Shift or Control click to select more than one.  Then right click -> Properties -> Account -> Users must change password at next logon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a very good and very useful tool for doing what you want.

http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/software/bulkadusers/default.aspx

You can do this by OU, by CSV import based on username for a unique identifier, lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using PowerShell and the [Quest PowerShell Commands for Active Directory](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).

This will:

1. Export all users to a text file
2. Open notepad, giving you an opportunity to remove any users that shouldn't be prompted for a password reset
3. Process the revised file, marking each user left as needing a password change on next login

Contents of PowerShell script:

```
# Variable for path, change to convenient location
$exportPath = "c:\Users.txt"
# Get all users, export only their user name to a text file
Get-QADUser | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | Out-File $exportPath
# Open notepad on this file
notepad $exportPath
# Write message to console
Write-Host "Using notepad, remove users not required to change password"
# Wait for user to press enter to continue
Read-Host "Press enter when ready"

# Read the text file back in, load an AD user for each line, and change their setting
Get-Content $exportPath | Get-QADUser | Set-QADUser -UserMustChangePassword $true
```